Is it possible to obtain the DockerFile (or equivalent) for SageMaker's prebuilt images (e.g. one of their sklearn containers)?
I am fairly new to Docker. I usually use SageMaker's prebuilt container images when deploying an endpoint for inference (e.g. with scikit-learn). I am interested in seeing the DockerFile (e.g. "source code") that AWS uses to create their prebuilt images, so I can use this as both a learning tool and a template for creating my own custom containers for use with a SageMaker endpoint.
For example, if I wanted to deploy a version of an ML framework that is not yet available in a prebuilt image, or if I want to have two frameworks installed and running simultaneously in a single container (e.g. both XGBoost and Sklearn). I know I can design custom containers from scratch, but I don't really want to change much from what is already on offer; just install a couple of extra python packages and maybe upgrade the python version.
Alternatively, is it possible to issue a "pip install" command to simply install or update python versions / packages when you initially deploy a SageMaker endpoint.
EDIT: I don't think the Dockerfiles for their images exist, so I just had build my own container from scratch with a custom Flask app.

Have you tried searching for the image in DockerHub or Github ? Some companies such as Microsoft have the source code for their Dockerfiles.

I did search DockerHub, there are AWS official images there but I couldn't find the SageMaker images.

A variety of container images for SageMaker are available as open-source projects.
For specific Deep Learning frameworks, AWS Deep Learning Container images are available for both training and inference purposes.
The source code, including the Dockerfiles, is hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers
In addition, there is the SageMaker Distribution, which comprises of Docker images designed for machine learning, data science, and visualization. These images can be used for interactive notebooks in SageMaker Studio or with SageMaker Processing or Training Jobs.
This project is also available on GitHub: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-distribution
